# delete[] trigger breakpoint

Tags: c++, pointers, triggers, breakpoints

This is my example code:

```
int main()
{
    const wchar_t *envpath = L"hello\\";
    const wchar_t *dir = L"hello2\\";
    const wchar_t *core = L"hello3";

    wchar_t *corepath = new wchar_t[
        wcslen(envpath) +
        wcslen(dir) +
        wcslen(core)
    ];

    wcscpy_s(corepath, wcslen(corepath) + wcslen(envpath) + 1, envpath);
    wcscat_s(corepath, wcslen(corepath) + wcslen(dir) + 1, dir);
    wcscat_s(corepath, wcslen(corepath) + wcslen(core) + 1, core);

    delete []corepath;
    return 0;
}
```

On the `delete []corepath` command, a breakpoint is triggered.
What could be the cause?

ALSO, If I rewrite the code this way:

```
    wcscpy_s(corepath, wcslen(envpath) + 1, envpath);
    wcscat_s(corepath, wcslen(corepath) + wcslen(dir) + 1, dir);
    wcscat_s(corepath, wcslen(corepath) + wcslen(core) + 1, core);
```

A Heap corruption is detected when deleting the pointer.

EDIT:

I think I should allocate corepath also with +1 to store the ending \0, right?

Comment: "I think I should allocate corepath also with +1 to store the ending \0, right?" Yes. Better still, use `std::wstring` to handle all the memory allocation correctly for you.

Comment: wcslen returns the length of the string, without the NULL termination character, so when you allocate corepath, you should account for the NULL termination character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space to contain the terminating zero. The last call to `wcscat_s` will write `'\0'` beyond the end of the buffer pointed to by `corepath`.

You're also lying to `wcscat_s` about the capacity of the buffer. The capacity is `wcslen(envpath) + wcslen(dir) + wcslen(core)`, yet you're passing `wcslen(corepath) + wcslen(core) + 1` instead.

You're also calling `wcslen(corepath)` before `corepath` is initialized.

The fixed code should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    const wchar_t *envpath = L"hello\\";
    const wchar_t *dir = L"hello2\\";
    const wchar_t *core = L"hello3";

    size_t cap = wcslen(envpath) +
        wcslen(dir) +
        wcslen(core) + 1;

    wchar_t *corepath = new wchar_t[cap];

    wcscpy_s(corepath, cap, envpath);
    wcscat_s(corepath, cap, dir);
    wcscat_s(corepath, cap, core);

    delete[] corepath;
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, the fixed code should look like this:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    const wchar_t *envpath = L"hello\\";
    const wchar_t *dir = L"hello2\\";
    const wchar_t *core = L"hello3";

    std::wstring corepath = envpath;
    corepath.append(dir);
    corepath.append(core);
}
```